# In postgresql, how to get diff of two date colmns with timestamp?

Tags: postgresql-8.3

I want the difference  two date columns and result should be as:
0.62222222222222222 if the two dates are same with timestamp.
In Oracle we can do this just by subtracting but that didn't work in PostgreSQL.

Can anyone please explain me with an example?

Comment: Why would subtracting two identical timestamp values result in 0.62222222222222222?

Comment: It is not idententical timestamp values. same date with some time difference.